# R: How many element of list 1 are in list 2/Number of occurences

Tags: r, list, compare

I would like to compare two lists (two rows of a data frame) and count how many differences I have between the two lists.

for instance:

```
list1=a,b,c,a
list2=a,a,d,d
```

two elements of list 1 are in list 2

I am able to do that with a loop and sum but it is very inefficient. Is there any function to do that in R?

I have checked setdiff and the compare package but did not find anything that helps.

Thanks for your ideas,

Vincent

My function looks like:

```
        NRebalancing=function(NamePresent)
        {
          Nbexchange=NamePresent[,2]
          Nbexchange=NamePresent[1,2]=0

          for (i in 2:nrow(NamePresent))
          {
            print(i)
            compteur=0
            NameNeeded=NamePresent[i,]
            NameNeeded=unique(NameNeeded)
            NameNeeded=na.omit(NameNeeded)
            for(j in 2:length(NameNeeded))
              #j=1 correspond a une date
            {
              compteur = compteur+(abs(sum(NamePresent[i,]==as.character(NameNeeded[j]))-sum(NamePresent[i-1,]==as.character(NameNeeded[j]))))
            }
          Nbexchange[i]=compteur  
          }

          return(Nbexchange)
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One main point: your list isn't an R list - that's something a bit special. You are using vectors:

```
R> is.vector(l1)
[1] TRUE
R> is.list(l1)
[1] FALSE
```

don't call variables `list1` if they are vectors.

---

Since you have a vector there are lots of possibilities open.

1. The `%in%` operator

   ```
   R> l1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
   R> l2 = c("a", "a", "d", "d")
   R> l1[l1 %in% l2]
    [1] "a" "d"
   ```
2. Or use `is.element`

   ```
   R> l1[is.element(l1, l2)]
    [1] "a" "d"
   ```
3. There is also `unique`:

   ```
   R> unique(l2)
    [1] "a" "d"
   ```

   Following your comment to @mrdwab, you can count the number of occurances using a combination of `sapply` and `unique`

   ```
   sapply(unique(l1), function(i) sum(i==l2))
   ```

   `i==l2` checks for membership, `sum` counts the number of times TRUE appears and `sapply` is basically just a for loop over `unique(l1)`

   ```
   R> sapply(unique(l1), function(i) sum(i==l2))
   a b c d 
   2 0 0 2
   ```
4. A very nice suggestion from @mrdwab is to use `table` and `colSums`:

   ```
   R> table(l1, l2)
     l2 l1  
      a d
    a 1 0
    b 1 0
    c 0 1
    d 0 1
   R> colSums(table(l1, l2))
    a d 
    2 2
   ```

Comment: Sorry about the name. It is a vector from a data frame so the variable type could be different...I'll edit the question

Comment: Remember vectors can have different types: they could be characters, numeric or logicals

Comment: many thanks! That what I was looking for. Did not get time to edit my question :)

Comment: @csgillespie, +1 for the details and the different options. I think `table` plus `colSums` works nicely for this too.

Comment: @mrdwab Using table is very neat - it's not a function I use often.

Comment: @csgillespie, avoiding colSums: `table(l2[which(l2 %in% l1)])`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
list1 = c("a", "b", "c", "a")
list2 = c("a", "a", "d", "d")
list2 %in% list1
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

## Update

Since you're looking for frequencies, I also think it's natural to consider `table`.

Overall, I find the *question* somewhat confusing. Your question states that you are looking for number of occurrences in one list (`list2`) that are present in another list (`list1`), but in the accepted answer (and in my `coSums(table...` example, you are also counting `d`, which *does not appear* in `list1`. Thus, I am providing one last example using `table` and `%in%` which matches your question, but may not be what you are looking for. Here it is:

```
table(list2[which(list2 %in% list1)])

# a 
# 2
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to know how many times each element is present and not only if it is present.

Comment: for something like:
    
    list1 = c("a", "b", "c", "a")
    list2 = c("a", "a", "a", "a")
    list2 %in% list1

I would like to get 2

Comment: @VincentH, `TRUE` counts as `1` and `FALSE` as `0`, so `sum(list2 %in% list1)` would give you `2`.

Comment: @VincentH, in the example data in your comment, why would you expect to get `2` as the answer? `a` is in `list1` and `a` appears 4 times in  `list2`, so why don't you expect `4` as the answer?

Comment: I am sorry for being unclear. In fact I want to count how many times an element in list2 was present in list1